# Is there a way to combine hard-coded column headers with an 'exec stored procedure' using BCP?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

I've seen the hack to add the column headers to a select query but I have a stored procedure that has a lot of functionality in it. How do I `UNION ALL` my column headers with my stored procedure like:

```
BCP "Select 'col1', 'col2' UNION ALL exec Stored_Proc" queryout c:\BCP\file.out -c -T -S Servername
```

So I'm trying to produce a csv file with my hard-coded headers (or table headers) and then the results of my query (which is in the stored procedure).

Thanks!

Also, one more thing, I'm running this bcp call from a batch file so I can add a date to the filename of my csv like:

```
set var=export_Data_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.csv

bcp "exec dbo..Extract_Data" queryout c:\BCP\%var% -c -t, -T -S Servername
```

Comment: As long as you can do more than just call `bcp` and you know the columns in advance, I wouldn't use this hack at all (the `UNION ALL` can screw things up royally by forcing your columns to convert to `VARCHAR`s, aside from not working with stored procedure calls, as you've discovered). `bcp` to one file, `ECHO` your headers to another, then `COPY headers+data result` them together.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks #Jeroen Mostert. How do I ECHO the headers to a file from the command line (so I can add it to my batch file)?

Comment: `ECHO col1,col2,col3 > columns.csv` should do.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks Jeroen!!